# UTF-8 byte order mark appears when using os.system() but not when printing

Tags: python, os.system, byte-order-mark

I have an issue where when I print a command that I want the python script to run, it prints in perfect syntax, however, when I try to use that exact same variable in order to run the command using `os.system()` it won't run and gives me an error. See Below:

```
wholecommand = '''python3 mysshpass.py --password "%s" ssh %s "%s" ''' % (password, sshprefix, runcommand)
print(wholecommand)
response = os.system(wholecommand)
```

So in this instance I've defined the command I want to run based off of some random variables but when I run this code it returns with the following:

```
python3 mysshpass.py --password "***" ssh root@10.245.10.72 "echo -e '***
***' | passwd"
ssh: Could not resolve hostname \357\273\27710.245.10.72: Name or service not known
```

The issue here is that for whatever reason my script is inserting **\357\273\277** into the thread where the ip address goes and I just can't figure out why.

Comment: what is meaning of `python3 mysshpass.py --password "***" ssh root@10.245.10.72 "echo -e '***' | passwd"`? python command with arguments? two bash commands in one line? python's `print` output? what is contents of `mysshpass.py`?

Comment: maybe you should check source code of `mysshpass.py` and use it as any other script/module - using `import mysshpass` without `os.system`

Comment: do you get values `password, sshprefix, runcommand` from file? Maybe you should fix this file.

Comment: or maybe you should simply use `sshprefix.replace('\357\273\277', '')`

Comment: Consider the security implication: Every process in that system will know your password. Professionally, ssh keys are deployed with installation, and you use that. (Everybody has access to command line of other commands, but permission of filesystems are enforced)